# BodyPix - Error: No backend found in registry

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to setup BodyPix via the tutorial on the TensorFlow website, and I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No backend found in registry.
    at Engine.getSortedBackends (engine.js:248)
    at Engine.initializeBackendsAndReturnBest (engine.js:257)
    at Engine.get backend [as backend] (engine.js:94)
    at Engine.makeTensor (engine.js:556)
    at makeTensor (tensor_ops_util.js:57)
    at tensor (tensor.js:48)
    at Module.decodeWeights (io_utils.js:212)
    at GraphModel.loadSync (graph_model.js:118)
    at GraphModel.load (graph_model.js:102)
    at async loadGraphModel (graph_model.js:348)
```

I tried installing several packages that I thought might help, but I'm really not sure what to do now.. appreciate any input I could get.

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/body-pix": "^2.0.5",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^2.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^2.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^2.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

**index.js**

```
import * as bodyPix from '@tensorflow-models/body-pix';

const img = document.getElementById('image');

async function loadAndPredict() {
  const net = await bodyPix.load(/** optional arguments, see below **/);

  /**
   * One of (see documentation below):
   *   - net.segmentPerson
   *   - net.segmentPersonParts
   *   - net.segmentMultiPerson
   *   - net.segmentMultiPersonParts
   * See documentation below for details on each method.
   */
  const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(img);
  console.log(segmentation);
}
loadAndPredict();
```

Answer (score 7):

I was using the same version of `body-pix` and ran into the exact same issue. I resolved the problem by importing modules from `@tensorflow/tfjs` package. It seems importing these modules is necessary to register the backends. You may have to do the following to fix this issue:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
...

console.log('Using TensorFlow backend: ', tf.getBackend());
loadAndPredict();
```

Comment: Did it work giantqtipz?

Prashant, what is the purpose of backend registry?
I am getting similar issue but with different library
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901482/tensorflow-library-upgradation

Comment: @RohitMittal Tensorflow supports multiple backends. It seems that when a backend is initialised, it registers itself with the backend registry. If the registration doesn't happen or fails for some reason, Tensorflow.js complains about the missing backend.

More information on backends is available at:

https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/platform_environment#backends